# OOB Content Query Web Part Paging

Tags: content-query-web-part

How can I implement paging (no code and probably using XSLT) in the OOB CQWP?

Answer (score 2):

So I would use something like a jQuery plugin to do the actual pagination, and you will definitely need to modify the XSLT.

Basically, your customised xslt would have to:

- Output html in the format expected by the plugin
- Output  tags to include js files for jquery and the plugin
- Output a  tag to attach the plugin to your html

Urls that might help with modifying the cqwp

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb447557.aspx
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/ecm/configuring-and-customizing-the-content-query-web-part

Some urls that might help with the paging

- http://plugins.jquery.com/project/pagination
- http://plugins.jquery.com/plugin-tags/pager